# How to get text with some specific tags' text together in a tag by scrapy in python?

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy, selector

I am new to **scrapy**. I want to crawl some data from the web. I got the html document like below.

```
<div class="user-info">
    <p class="user-img">
        something in p tag
    </p>
    <em>text</em> data I want
    <a href="#">
        something in a tag
    </a>
</div>
```

I want to get the **text data I want** only. But the **text** is in the tag `<em></em>`. So if I use `div[contains(@class, "user-info")]/text()`, I can get **data I want** only. If I use `div[contains(@class, "user-info")]/node()` I get all the tags inside `div.user-info`, and also `div[contains(@class, "user-info")]/node()/text()`. So the question is, how can I get the **text** and the **data I want** together to be **text data I want**?

Answer (score 1):

If you want all nodes after `<p class="user-img">` and before `<a href="#">something in a tag</a>`, you can use the [`following` axis](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#axes):

> the following axis contains all nodes in the same document as the context node that are after the context node in document order, excluding any descendants and excluding attribute nodes and namespace nodes

```
>>> s = scrapy.Selector(text='''<div class="user-info">
...     <p class="user-img">
...         something in p tag
...     </p>
...     <em>text</em> data I want
...     <a href="#">
...         something in a tag
...     </a>
... </div>''')
>>> s.css('p.user-img')
[<Selector xpath="descendant-or-self::p[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' user-img ')]" data='<p class="user-img">\n        something i'>]

>>> s.css('p.user-img').xpath('following::text()[following::a]').getall()
['\n    ', 'text', ' data I want\n    ']

>>> ''.join(s.css('p.user-img').xpath('following::text()[following::a]').getall())
'\n    text data I want\n    '
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below `XPath` to get two required text nodes concatenated:

```
concat(//div[@class="user-info"]/em/text(), " ", //div[@class="user-info"]/text()[3])
```

Comment: thanks, but em maybe in data for example: text <em>data</em> I want, lost it's order.

Comment: try `//div[@class="user-info"]//text()[not(parent::a or parent::p)]`

Answer (score -1):

I replace the `<em>` and `</em>` with `""`, and then use `div[contains(@class, "user-info")]/text()`